# Why is PHP form not sending email

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am trying to send email using jquery and PHP but somehow I am not receiving emails even when PHP executes successfully.

This is my javascript code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this),
            url = $form.attr('action');
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            message: $('#message').val()
        });
        posting.done(function(data) {
            $("#result").empty().append('Thank you for contacting. Will get back to you as sson as possible.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "email@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
        $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Portfolio form submission";   

        $message = $name . " " . $email . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];    

        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
?>
```

When I submit the form, and inspect the dom, I see the results are good.
In the XHR details, it shows:

```
statusText: "OK"
```

Am i doing something wrong here?

Edit:
Adding HTML as requested:

```
<form class="no-bottom" id="formoid" action="contact.php" title="" method="post">
    <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="underline" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name..." required>
    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="underline" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email..." required>
    <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
    <textarea class="underline" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Here goes the message..." required></textarea>
    <div class="margin-1"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send it">
</form>
```

Comment: Checking `isset($_POST['submit'])` when it is not sent from client

Comment: Where are you executing this PHP-Code ? Do you have an MailServer installed and configured ?

Comment: Provide your `html` here.

Comment: I am executing this code my my website. It has PHP support.

Comment: Check out Example #2 to here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Try to `print_r($_POST);` in **contact.php** before `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset($_POST['submit'])` is checking if the key `submit` is present in the date Posted from the client.

However, the data sent from client does not include it.

```
var posting = $.post(url, {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    message: $('#message').val()
});
```

To make it work, you can either add it in POST data or check another key in the server.

```
var posting = $.post(url, {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    message: $('#message').val(),
    submit: 'anythingTruthyHere' // Added `submit` key
});
```

OR, you can check if the `email` is present in the POST data

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // send mail code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use good lib [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Using PHPMailer you can easily set smtp server address, port and auth. If you want to send email from your local computer, you must set up smtp server locally (like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org)).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a brief idea, instead of writing the code like this, separate the files. Connect the form action to some sendemail.php and write your php code of sending email there and at last write the following

```
header("Location: contact.php");
```

No need of javascript and don't make the code complex.This should help mostly.

Comment: Hi, my PHP is already a separate file. You can see that in my form, I call a separate PHP file.